# Apache Fails to Start

Tags: apache, xampp, port

I use a Mac and am trying to learn to use My SQL databases for my website. When I installed XAMPP I ran into trouble. XAMPP starts fine, FTP starts fine, Apache won't start. Message I get is: /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin/apachectl: line 70: ulimit: open files: cannot modify limit: Invalid argument (48)Address already in use: make_sock: could not bind to address [::]:80 (48)Address already in use: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:80 no listening sockets available, shutting down Unable to open logs.

I have searched this site and others looking for a solution and nothing I have tried has allowed Apache to start. When I looked at who was using port 80. Dropbox was (I closed it) There is also a user root (LISTEN) and _www (LISTEN).

Comment: Apache is already (or still) running.

Comment: When I look at my XAMPP Controls it says Apache Not Running; MySQL Running; FTP Running

Comment: Hmm, something else has already grabbed port 80 then... Skype or something like that?

Comment: When I looked at who was using port 80. Dropbox was (I closed it) There is also a user root (LISTEN) and _www (LISTEN).